# PHP Unable to do file operations file (fopen, fwrite, fclose)

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fread, fclose

I am facing an issue. This is what my script looks like:

```
$file = fopen("logs/log.php", "r+") or die("Kan bestand (1) niet openen bradda!");
$content = fread($file, filesize("logs/log.php"));
fclose($file);
$filee = fopen("logs/log.php", "r+") or die("Kan bestand (2) niet openen bradda!");
$newcontent = $content.'<br /><b>'.$userRow['userId'].'   -   '.$userRow['userName'].'     -     '.$search;
fwrite($filee, $newcontent) or die("Kan bestand (3) niet openen bradda!");
fclose($filee);
```

My purpose is to create a log. Everytime a user searches for a key word, it must be logged in the file 'log.php'.
I am running on a VPS (Windows server), and as i understood from another person with PHP experience, told me the directory/path should be different. Because it is not a webhost.
If that is exactly true, i don't know. But i hope you guys can help me out with this issue.

Comment: Shouldn't you be logging to a database table?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Terry what if the error is a database problem? Logging to a file is probably slightly more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:
1) Create log folder in your website root directory.
2) Check your log folder read/write permission. (required permission 777)
3) Use a+ on the place of r+. Because in r+ file pointer starts at the beginning of the file and in a+ the existing data in file is preserved. File pointer starts at the end of the file. Creates a new file if the file doesn’t exist.

Comment: I wouldn't put a log file in the website directory - it would be readable by everyone who goes to the website, unless you're very careful.

Comment: Then my advicde is: create virtual directory that will be accessible from apache (from php).

Comment: you don't want apache to be able to see it (that was my original point), only PHP should be able to access it.